# 2012 macbook pro 13" sound drops out

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I am a dj playing live in a club.  after playing live music with traktor software for a couple of hours sound gets muddy and starts getting muffled then fades out/drop out.I am using a s4 mk2 traktor controller which has a sound card.  When i closed the program the let the system's quick player run it did the same time, but it was still running through usb controller.

Comment: It's really difficult to imagine how digital audio can 'get muffled, then fade out' - which would initially make me suspect the analog part of your rig.

Comment: Does the problem disappear after a restart?

Comment: try playing with settings in audio midi.app (can be found in launchpad under utilities or in applications under utilities) it should house the problem. I've had the same kind of problems... you could be using the wrong sample rate for the equipment or just the wrong bit depth. here's my setup: http://i.imgur.com/CxV54aX.png

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found was to hook up my [traktor 2 audio interface](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-audio-interfaces/traktor-audio-2/), which not only corrected the problem but gave me a bigger better sound.